# Json-ld schema for brand page?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to understand how to define schema `Brand` on a brand page.

Using the example of a website selling shoes, apart from category pages, there will be brand pages listing all products (they link out to their respective product page) of the respective brand. So, at a high level what I figure will be an approach like this:

```
- schema: CollectionPage, defining the WebPage
- schema: Brand, connected to CollectionPage using `mainEntityOfPage`
- schema: ItemList, list of the brand's products displayed
```

In the above, I am not able to connect the ItemList to Brand, so it's hanging (Google SDTT is showing 2 independent schemas on the page).

There's another option, where we connect the ItemList to CollectionPage using `mainEntityOfPage` but then Brand will be hanging.

Is there some way to connect all the 3 schemas?

If not, are there alternate methods of defining the 3 things so that we can connect them?

A point to note here is that both `Brand` and `ItemList` has `name` property and they hold the same values, but that doesn't connect them, as I understand.

Any insight into this will help.

Comment: Does the page also say something about the brand (i.e., facts, history etc.)?

Comment: @unor No, nothing much about the brands, just `name` and `url`. It's for ecommerce.

Comment: @unor ... (continuing) Can also have an image/logo. In future, can have `similarTo` an wikipedia page of the brand (or the brand's authoritative page). That's max content about the brand on the page.

Comment: @unor Do you have any thoughts on this? My intent is to have Google SDTT show a single schema of the brand page (connecting the Page, Brand and it's products).

Answer (score 0):

use these combinations

`Brand/subjectOf/WebPage`

`Product/brand/Brand`

`ItemList/itemListElement/Product`

linked using the relevant `@id`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `about`. Looking at it first time, I get the feeling that `about` (inv of `subjectOf`) and `mainEntity` mean the same (but can't be, as both exists). Question is: on brand page, if `about` is used to refer to `Brand` schema, can we rightly use `mainEntity` also to refer to `ItemList` holding all the products of the brand? (If not, how to link `ItemList` to the WebPage/CollectionPage?)

Comment: Think "directionally". I proposed `Brand/subjectOf/WebPage` because that will force `Brand` to be the main element in GSDTT. Alternatively, `WebPage/about/Brand` will set `WebPage` as the main element. From your question, I assumed orinality was `Brand`. If that's not true, set the order (thru relationships/predicates) that you are seeking. Do you need this "written up" or can you extrapolate from my answer above?

Comment: Also, the answer will ONLY work if you use `@id` to link relationships.

Comment: I was not aware of the difference in main element due to the declaration -- I thought `about` or `subjectOf` can be used to acheive the same definition, used based on our implementation's needs.

Comment: Yes, the page is a brand page, that declares the brand name/desc and _also_ lists the products that the brand carries. Now, given your form of implementation using `Brand/subjectOf/WebPage`, which _property_ do I use to list the products that the brand carries? (I am aware of `@id`, but which _property_ to use for the linkage).

Comment: True, the terms represent inverse relationships. But I assumed that you are thinking: what will Google search display? Hence my answer. If not, then you can use all inverse pairs (e.g. `hasPart` `isPartOf` etc.)

Comment: This is why I answered as I did - I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to express (I'm not saying you are being vague; I'm simply saying: you need to be more explicit). A `Brand` could be linked to 2+ `Product` (a 1:m relationship). `Brand` could be linked to 2+ `Webpage`. Etc. See the documentation for the `property` specific to the `@Type`. But you can repeat `property` from `@Thing` on every `@Type` (`name` `description` `alternativeName` etc.)

Comment: I was not aware I didn't mention about the brand's `1:m` relationship with it's products (I thought the 3rd line in my example talks about the schema of using `ItemList` for the brand's displayed products on the page).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last sentence. If there are a list of products (belonging to the brand, displayed on the brand page), say in `ItemList`, I don't find which property of the page to use to connect it to. I had checked/tried before posting this query.

Comment: `ItemList/itemListElement/ListItem/item/{Thing}` where {Thing} is your `@Product` `@id` (which you have previously marked-up and identified with `@id`

Comment: I have this. The problem: Google SDTT shows 2 independent schemas in the page, ie they are not connected. To connect them, I need to connect this `ItemList` to the `Brand` (or, page). I am not finding any property of the schema `Brand` to connect the `ItemList` to (if I do it to the `WebPage`, only option is `mainEntity`, but I I think I can't use it's as I used `about` to link the brand -- didn't find any material online to appreciate the difference between `about` and `mainEntity`).

Comment: i can't help any more without data. just because GSDTT shows 2+ `@Types` does not mean they are not linked. but we've done this many times and i guarantee that the correct implementation of my advice above will be properly understood by google. you can look at alternative 'views' on JSON-LD Playground and Structured Data Linter to confirm the `@graph`

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for your much help (I learned `about`/`subjectOf` from you).